# implement a linear gradient on a tube

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have the following function, which traces out a circle for a certain value of $f$,

$f(x, y, z) = \exp(-x^2)\exp(-z^2)$.

For a given $f$, the circle has the same value for all $y$ in my coordinate system $(x, y, z)$. In other words, it is a **tube**. However, I am interested in including a gradient such that the tube increases linearly along $y$. Is there a way to achieve this?

To summarize: How can I make the above tube increase linearly along $y$?

Comment: It seems multiplying $f$ with $y$ shall suffice.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I thoight about that too, but that wont work - because in that case the tube will have the value $0$ at $f(x, 0, z)$, whereas it should trace out a circle

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but here is a place [to graph 3d surfaces](http://web.monroecc.edu/manila/webfiles/calcNSF/JavaCode/CalcPlot3D.htm). You can experiment with $z=exp(-x^2-y^2)$ to start. That gives a bump not a tube.

Comment: $c=\exp(-x^2-z^2)$ (with $c$ constant) traces out a circle for all $y$, so it is a tube along the direction $y$

Comment: @BillyJean If $a$ *linearly* grows with $b$, then $a = kb$ plus a shift term, w/o looking at shift, when $b = 0$, $a$ has to be zero. What you can do is then multiplying something like $(y+1)$ when $y\geq 0$ and $(-y+1)$ when $y<0$, but that would result a jump in $\partial_y f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y,z)$ forms a circle in the plane $y=c$, with centre at $(x,y,z)=(0,c,0)$. I assume when you say "increase", you want the centre of the circle to be at a larger $z$ value.

Transforming variables $z'=z-f(y)$ shifts the centre of the circle for the function $f(x,y,z')$ in the plane $y=c$ to $(0,c,f(c))$. Choosing a linear function for $f(y)$ with $f(y)>0$ on the region you are interested in will suffice.

Comment: Say $f(y)=y$, it seems $\nabla e^{-x^2-(z-y)^2}$ won't produce a  gradient linearly along $y$?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao No, the function does not change linearly with $y$. As I mentioned, I am assuming the *centre* is moving. This transformation does move the centre linearly with y. It is unclear what is meant by "...the tube increases linearly...".